I cannot navigate to next page
In my code I have checked everything but no error and even if the input I gave for login is there in my firebase database it is not going to next page.
here is the code:
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loginuicolors/mic.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class MyLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyLogin({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyLoginState createState() => _MyLoginState();
}

class _MyLoginState extends State<MyLogin> {
  String email = "", password = "";

  TextEditingController mailcontroller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();

  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  userLogin(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
        final email = mailcontroller.text;
        final password = passwordcontroller.text;

        await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
        print('Login successful');

        if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'ic');
        }
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
            content: Text(
              "No User Found for that Email",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
            content: Text(
              "Wrong Password Provided by User",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      // Handle other exceptions here
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/login.png'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, top: 130),
              child: const Text(
                'Welcome\nBack',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 33),
              ),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, right: 35),
                      child: Form(
                        key: _formkey,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            TextFormField(
                              controller: mailcontroller,
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                fillColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                                filled: true,
                                hintText: "Email",
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                              ),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Please enter some text';
                                }
                                mailcontroller.text = value;
                                return null;
                              },
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              controller: passwordcontroller,
                              style: const TextStyle(),
                              obscureText: true,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                fillColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                                filled: true,
                                hintText: "Password",
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                              ),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Please enter some text';
                                }
                                passwordcontroller.text = value;
                                return null;
                              },
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 40,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                const Text(
                                  'Sign in',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 27,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                ),
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 30,
                                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xff4c505b),
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      /*if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          email = mailcontroller.text;
                                          password = passwordcontroller.text;
                                        });
                                        await userLogin(
                                            context); // Pass context here
                                      }*/
                                      await userLogin(context);
                                    },
                                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 40,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'register');
                                  },
                                  style: const ButtonStyle(),
                                  child: const Text(
                                    'Sign Up',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                      color: Color(0xff4c505b),
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => const MicScreen(),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  child: const Text(
                                    'Forgot Password',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                      color: Color(0xff4c505b),
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


i tried logging in i want to know what my problem is so that i can verify.the above code basically is for logging in a website after signing in ,the signing process was successful and the data was added successfully to firebase database but for checking when entered right email and password it is not working.

There's quite a lot of code in your question and Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. It's much more likely somebody can help if you debug the code locally, and tell us the result of that. So: set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line. If you do this, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?
